# Any use of a keyed object should be wrapped in React.addons.createFragment(object)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
let playerInfo = [{
    name: 'jose',
    country: 'USA',
    age: 47 
}];

export default class PlayersInfo extends React.Component {
    static getProps() {
        return {};
    }
    render() {
        let playerInf = playerInfo.map((playerData, index) => {
            return <div className="item" key={index}>{playerData}</div>
        });

        return <div>

                 <div>
                    {playerInf}
                 </div>

            <RouteHandler />
        </div>;
    }
```

Why am I getting this error in the browser's console?

> Warning: Any use of a keyed object should be wrapped in React.addons.createFragment(object) before being passed as a child.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I put together a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/zedixa/2/edit?js,output) for you. Basically, the warning comes from this line:

```
return <div className="item" key={index}>{playerData}</div>
```

It's because `playerData` is an object and ReactJS doesn't know how to render it.

If you change that to the following, it won't give you the warning:

```
return (
  <div className="item" key={index}>
    <div>Name: {playerData.name}</div>
    <div>Country: {playerData.country}</div>
    <div>Age: {playerData.age}</div>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why am I getting this error in the browser's console?

Because you are passing an **object** (`playerData`) as child to a React Component.

Comment: what is the way to fix this ?

Comment: Follow the warning: *"Any use of a keyed object should be wrapped in React.addons.createFragment(object) before being passed as a child."* or don't pass an object. What are you trying to achieve by passing the object?

Comment: all I am doing is trying to render the info in `playerInfo`

Comment: I understand that, but just like you are converting the array of objects to an array of elements, you have to decide what elements you want to convert each object to, I.e how render the name, age, etc.

Comment: in the DOM I need something like: <p>Name: {playerData.name}</p><p>Age: {playerData.age}</p>

Comment: Then pass that instead of the object itself.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to run into this when rendering a `Date` object by mistake. You need to stringify these manually:

Produces warning:

```
<div>{ new Date() }</div>
```

Works ok:

```
<div>{ String(new Date()) }</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
return <div>
           <div>
              {playerInf}
           </div>

           <div>      
             <RouteHandler />
           </div>;
       </div>
}
```